# What's wrong to mix jQuery with backbone.js/angular.js/ember.js?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, backbone.js, ember.js

I came from backend dev to frontend dev just recently, so I'm a totally newbie here and having a lot troubles cleaning my head up.

One of the problems is that I was trying to integrate twitter-bootstrap-3 with one of the mvvm frameworks naming backbone.js, angular.js and ember.js. I was really confused to see some repos in GH trying to rewrite some js part of bootstrap. What's wrong with jQuery in these frameworks? Would it be wrong to mix jQuery code into these frameworks? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you concerned about using jquery with those MVVM frameworks or using twitter bootstrap? Those end up being two very different balls of wax. Jquery is fine to use with with them, and for complex dom manipulation its needed. Personally, using directives properly, jqlite has always been enough with angular. Twitter bootstrap has conflict issues I can elaborate on if that's going to be an issue.

Comment: @DylanWatt: I'm just confused why cannot just pull in bootstrap and any one of the MVVM frameworks, why rewrite the js part for bootstrap?

Comment: This will help with some answers [thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Comment: @charlietfl: That's a great SO post. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

I can only speak to Angular.js for conflicts with bootstrap. On of the main issues is that bootstrap, by default, uses the `location.hash` a lot for things like `data-toggle` actions. This conflicts with angular's route management, which uses the hash as the route for your SPA.

Also, if you want to drive bootstrap actions, like a modal, by actions taken in the Angular runtime, it's much easier to do using `ui.bootstrap`, which provides services and directives that work well with angular.

I'd assume similar issues can come up with ember, etc.

Note that you can, in theory, use them at the same time, they are not inherently incompatible, but it can be painful to marry them without using preexisting solutions.

Comment: Yeah, that project hit on me yesterday. But 458 unresolved issues is just scary.

Comment: Its a very solid library. I use it anytime I use angular and tbs together, and i've never had an issue.

Comment: Great, you've just cleared the cloud away. I've definitely try it.